# Making the Dropdown title in the nav clockable option

Tags: drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm using the getbootstrap code for default navbar.
I want the title name of Drop-down (Test2) also to link to a html page. I added the linkage for the href, however when I'm running the page and clicking on the Drop-down text (Text2) nothing happened

```
    <div class="container-fluid">


        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

        <a class="navbar-brand">Test</a>


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-header" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="test1.html">test1</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="test2.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Test2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="test21.html">Test21</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test22">Create Test22</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test23.html">Test23</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="test3.html">Test3</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test4.html">Test4</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>


    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

</nav>
```

Comment: logically it's not possible! because if you do it , and user click on href="test2.html" , user never can see the dropdown menus!

Comment: Is this a technical limitation or a logic limitation?

Comment: technically its possible with simple Jquery Code